# grunt/compass producing empty destination stylesheet

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm figuring out grunt and compass. I'm using 'grunt-contrib-compass'.

When I run 'grunt', and edit my sass, grunt reports:

> > File "css/site.sass" changed.
> >         Done, without errors.

However, my destination stylesheet is empty.

I think I'm missing a config option that tells grunt where to write the css file to. But I haven't been able to figure out how to complete the config.

This is what I have:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


    compass : {
        dist: {
        options : {
        sassDir: 'sass',
        cssDir: 'css',
        imageDir: 'img',
        fontsDir: 'fonts',
        files : ['sass/*.sass'] ,
        watch : 'true',
        debugInfo: 'true',
        force : 'true'
        }
       }
    },

        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['css/*.css', '*.php', 'templates*.php'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            },

        options : {
        livereload: true,
        files: [
            'css/site.css', 'js/*.js', '*.html', 'templates/*.php',
            '*.php', 'assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
        }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch', 'compass']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs:](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass)

> This task requires you to have Ruby, Sass, and Compass >=0.12.2
>   installed. If you're on OS X or Linux you probably already have Ruby
>   installed; test with ruby -v in your terminal. When you've confirmed
>   you have Ruby installed, run gem update --system && gem install
>   compass to install Compass and Sass.

Make sure you've done that. [Also, you didn't specify a *target*](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks). Perhaps simply changing your config to this will work.

```
compass : {
    dist: {
        options : {
            sassDir: 'css',
            cssDir: 'css',
            debug: 'true'
        }
    }
},
```

Edit: It may be that what you have in the watch config is overriding the sass target. Try this instead:

```
    watch: {
        sass: {
            files: ['sass/**/*.sass'],
            tasks: ['compass']
        },
        css: {
            options: {
                livereload: true;
            }
            files: ['css/**/*.css'],
            tasks: []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Ben. I've updated the config in my question. I've got ruby, compass and sass installed, tested and working. Wrapping the options object in 'dist' didn't result in anything different, I'm afraid.

Comment: This line in your Gruntfile is unnecessary: `grunt.registerTask('default',['watch', 'compass']);` - remove that and try simply running `grunt watch`. (Your `compass` task on there will never run as `grunt watch` is a blocking task).